# UserWarning: Glyph 26 () missing from current font

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I keep getting error:

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py:151: UserWarning: Glyph 26 () missing from current font.
  fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
```

With the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

class Raman:
    def __init__(self):
        '''Initialise the class instance'''
    
    def readcsv(self,filename,skipheader=2):
        '''
        Returns the xth column from an input csv file 

        filename : Input csv filename
        '''
        data = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding= 'unicode_escape')
        data2 = data.to_numpy()
        x = data2[:,0]
        y1 = data2[:,1]
        y2 = data2[:,2]
        y3 = data2[:,3]
        av = data2[:,4]
        
        return (x,y1,y2,y3,av)
    
    
    def plotRaman(self, x, y, maxh=300,title='Raman'):
        '''
        Plot Raman spectrum
        '''
        plt.plot(x, y,lw=0.8)
        plt.xlabel("Raman shift")
        plt.ylabel("Intensity")
        plt.title(title)
        plt.show()
        
        
# Introduce class
s = Raman()

#Import csv files 
x_0201, y1_0201, y2_0201, y3_0201, y_0201  = s.readcsv("02_01.csv")
#Plot graph
s.plotRaman(x_0201,y_0201,900,'0201')
```

My plot output looks like this:

[image]

Everything else runs fine other than the plot output.

I've tried resetting Anaconda/ Spyder which I am using and it doesn't work.

Comment: it is not error but only warning. And problem can be system font, not Python code, You may have some char in data which doesn't exist in font. maybe you should run code with every row of data separatelly to find out which row makes problem.